# CustomBaseAdapter ошибка

Tags: android

У меня есть адаптер:

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends BaseAdapter {
    private static String TAG = "myApplication";
    private static String MSG = "Adapter: ";

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[][] words_form_1;
    private final String[][] words_form_2;

    public CustomListAdapter_Words(Activity context, String[][] words_form_1, String[][] words_form_2) {
        this.context = context;
        this.words_form_1 = words_form_1;
        this.words_form_2 = words_form_2;
    }

    static class ViewHolder_form_1 {
        public TextView textView_1_form_1;
        public TextView textView_2_form_1;
        public TextView textView_3_form_1;
    }

    static class ViewHolder_form_2 {
        public TextView textView_1_form_2;
        public TextView textView_2_form_2;
        public TextView textView_3_form_2;
        public TextView textView_4_form_2;
        public TextView textView_5_form_2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder_form_1 holder_1;
        ViewHolder_form_2 holder_2;

        View rowView_1 = convertView;
        View rowView_2 = convertView;

        if (rowView_1 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView_1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

            holder_1 = new ViewHolder_form_1();

            holder_1.textView_1_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            holder_1.textView_2_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            holder_1.textView_3_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

            rowView_1.setTag(holder_1);
        } else {
            holder_1 = (ViewHolder_form_1) rowView_1.getTag();
        }

        if (rowView_2 == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView_2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_2, null, true);

            holder_2 = new ViewHolder_form_2();

            holder_2.textView_1_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            holder_2.textView_2_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            holder_2.textView_3_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
            holder_2.textView_4_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
            holder_2.textView_5_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_5);

            rowView_2.setTag(holder_2);
        } else {
            holder_2 = (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();
        }

        if (position < words_form_1.length) {
            holder_1.textView_1_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][0]);
            holder_1.textView_2_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][1]);
            holder_1.textView_3_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][2]);

            return rowView_1;
        } else {
            holder_2.textView_1_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][0]);
            holder_2.textView_2_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][1]);
            holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][2]);
            holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][3]);
            holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][4]);

            return rowView_2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return words_form_1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        String[][] item = new String[1][8];

        item[0][0] = words_form_1[position][0];
        item[0][1] = words_form_1[position][1];
        item[0][2] = words_form_1[position][2];

        item[0][3] = words_form_2[position][0];
        item[0][4] = words_form_2[position][1];
        item[0][5] = words_form_2[position][2];
        item[0][6] = words_form_2[position][3];
        item[0][7] = words_form_2[position][4];

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Вот тут, при выполнении выскакивает ошибка:

```
if (rowView_2 == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView_2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_2, null, true);

        holder_2 = new ViewHolder_form_2();

        holder_2.textView_1_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
        holder_2.textView_2_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
        holder_2.textView_3_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
        holder_2.textView_4_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
        holder_2.textView_5_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_5);

        rowView_2.setTag(holder_2);
    } else {
        holder_2 = (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();
    }
```

Ошибка появляется на строке (75 строка): `holder_2 = (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();`

stacktrace ошибки:

```
11-03 15:50:26.301    4800-4800/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words$ViewHolder_form_1 cannot be cast to com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words$ViewHolder_form_2
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words.getView(CustomListAdapter_Words.java:75)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3087)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3361)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Само приложение крашится, когда я пролистываю `ListView` с этим адаптером, при чем первые 45 элементов (больше не помещается на экран) загружаются без сбоев. Ошибка происходит ТОЛЬКО при пролистывании. В сам адаптер поступает два двумерных массива по 100 элементов.

Что я делаю не так? Из-за чего крашится приложение?

---

С таким кодом:

```
   public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends BaseAdapter {
        private static String TAG = "myApplication";
        private static String MSG = "Adapter: ";

        private final Activity context;
        private final String[][] words_form_1;
        private final String[][] words_form_2;

        public CustomListAdapter_Words(Activity context, String[][] words_form_1, String[][] words_form_2) {
            this.context = context;
            this.words_form_1 = words_form_1;
            this.words_form_2 = words_form_2;
        }

        static class ViewHolder_form_1 {
            public TextView textView_1_form_1;
            public TextView textView_2_form_1;
            public TextView textView_3_form_1;
        }

        static class ViewHolder_form_2 {
            public TextView textView_1_form_2;
            public TextView textView_2_form_2;
            public TextView textView_3_form_2;
            public TextView textView_4_form_2;
            public TextView textView_5_form_2;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (position < words_form_1.length) {
                ViewHolder_form_1 holder_1;
                View rowView_1 = convertView;

                if (rowView_1 == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    rowView_1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

                    holder_1 = new ViewHolder_form_1();

                    holder_1.textView_1_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    holder_1.textView_2_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                    holder_1.textView_3_form_1 = (TextView) rowView_1.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

                    rowView_1.setTag(holder_1);
                } else {
                    holder_1 = (ViewHolder_form_1) rowView_1.getTag();
                }

                holder_1.textView_1_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][0]);
                holder_1.textView_2_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][1]);
                holder_1.textView_3_form_1.setText(words_form_1[position][2]);

                return rowView_1;
            } else {
                ViewHolder_form_2 holder_2;
                View rowView_2 = convertView;

                if (rowView_2 == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                    rowView_2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_2, null, true);

                    holder_2 = new ViewHolder_form_2();

                    holder_2.textView_1_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    holder_2.textView_2_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                    holder_2.textView_3_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
                    holder_2.textView_4_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
                    holder_2.textView_5_form_2 = (TextView) rowView_2.findViewById(R.id.text_5);

                    rowView_2.setTag(holder_2);
                } else { 
                    if(rowView_2.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder_form_2) {
                        holder_2 = (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();
                    } else {
                        holder_2 = new ViewHolder_form_2();
                    }
                }

                holder_2.textView_1_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][0]); //92 строка
                holder_2.textView_2_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][1]);
                holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][2]);
                holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][3]);
                holder_2.textView_3_form_2.setText(words_form_1[position][4]);

                return rowView_2;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return (words_form_1.length + words_form_2.length);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            String[][] item = new String[1][8];

            item[0][0] = words_form_1[position][0];
            item[0][1] = words_form_1[position][1];
            item[0][2] = words_form_1[position][2];

            item[0][3] = words_form_2[position][0];
            item[0][4] = words_form_2[position][1];
            item[0][5] = words_form_2[position][2];
            item[0][6] = words_form_2[position][3];
            item[0][7] = words_form_2[position][4];

            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType (int position) {
            return (position < words_form_1.length)?0:1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount () {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Ошибка такая:

```
11-03 19:52:20.757    1540-1540/? E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=100
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words.getView(CustomListAdapter_Words.java:92)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3640)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7341)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7322)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1415)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2446)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1915)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7428)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 19:52:20.773    1540-1540/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=100; index=100
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.CustomListAdapter_Words.getView(CustomListAdapter_Words.java:92)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3640)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7341)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7322)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1782)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1735)
            at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7315)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1415)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2446)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1915)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7428)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Я часто вижу вопросы на подобие ваших и все проблемы тупо из-за не знания работы адаптера и что для чего нужно. Перед тем как что-то делать вы почитайте нормальные туториалы или офф. туториалы от гугл

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, я не нашел нормальных туториалов на русском (кривые-то я прочитал, но про работу адаптера, что за чем в нем идет — ни слова), а для туториалов от гугла у меня знания английского сильно не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых - существует конвенции по написанию кода. [Java Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) и [Android-разработчика](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html), их настоятельно рекомендуется придерживаться, в частности при назначении имен. Так, имя переменной должно быть записано в [LowCamaelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) стиле. Быть кратким, но информативным.

Во вторых - у вас очевидное непонимание того, что вы делаете. Вам нужно уделить много больше внимания теории, затем уже пытаться реализовать что то на практике.

По коду:
Если вы решили использовать метод `getItemViewType()`, то его следует не только переопределить, но использовать по прямому назначению - для определения какой тип айтема требуется в текущей позиции.
Паттерн `ViewHolder` всего лишь хранит ссылки на виджеты, не стоит усложнять код, создавая множество этих холдеров и тем более строить на них бизнес-логику - паттерн для этого не предназначен. Более того, даже в моем примере класс `ViewHolder` избыточен, здесь достаточно определить пять полей для `TextView` - первый тип айтема будет использовать только первые три, второй тип - все пять. Переписывать еще и это мне было решительно лень.
Что возвращает ваш метод `getItem()` мне осилить не удалось, будем надеятся это именно то, что вам нужно получать от этого метода.

Вот как примерно должен выглядеть код адаптера. Естественно, я не буду создавать окружение, чтобы проверить его работоспособность, но , надеюсь, вы учтете различия в коде и дальше сможете действовать самостоятельно.

```
public class WordsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String TAG = "myApplication";
    private final String MSG = "Adapter: ";
    private final int FIRST_WORDS = 0;
    private final int SECOND_WORDS = 1;
    private final int FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH;

    private final Activity mContext;
    private final String[][] mWordsForm1;
    private final String[][] mWordsForm2;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public WordsAdapter(Activity context, String[][] wordsForm1, String[][] wordsForm2) {

        mContext = context;
        mWordsForm1 = wordsForm1;
        mWordsForm2 = wordsForm2;
        mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH = mWordsForm1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case FIRST_WORDS:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, null, true);

                    holder.textView1Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    holder.textView2Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                    holder.textView3Form1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
                    break;
                case SECOND_WORDS:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_2, null, true);

                    holder.textView1Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    holder.textView2Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                    holder.textView3Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_3);
                    holder.textView4Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_4);
                    holder.textView5Form2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_5);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        switch (type){
            case FIRST_WORDS:
                holder.textView1Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][0]);
                holder.textView2Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][1]);
                holder.textView3Form1.setText(mWordsForm1[position][2]);
                break;
            case SECOND_WORDS:
                holder.textView1Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][0]);
                holder.textView2Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][1]);
                holder.textView3Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][2]);
                holder.textView3Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH ][3]);
                holder.textView3Form2.setText(mWordsForm2[position - FIRST_ARRAY_LENGTH][4]);
                break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (mWordsForm1.length + mWordsForm2.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType (int position) {
        return (position < mWordsForm1.length) ? FIRST_WORDS:SECOND_WORDS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount () {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        String[][] item = new String[1][8];

        item[0][0] = mWordsForm1[position][0];
        item[0][1] = mWordsForm1[position][1];
        item[0][2] = mWordsForm1[position][2];

        item[0][3] = mWordsForm2[position][0];
        item[0][4] = mWordsForm2[position][1];
        item[0][5] = mWordsForm2[position][2];
        item[0][6] = mWordsForm2[position][3];
        item[0][7] = mWordsForm2[position][4];

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView1Form1;
        public TextView textView2Form1;
        public TextView textView3Form1;
        public TextView textView1Form2;
        public TextView textView2Form2;
        public TextView textView3Form2;
        public TextView textView4Form2;
        public TextView textView5Form2;
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас ошибочка тут, кою я и сам вчера не заметил, а ТС таки нашёл (см. коммент по моим ответом). Из второго массива значения надо не по позиции брать, а по `position-FIRST_ARRAY_LENGHT`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, точно.

Comment: С Вашим кодом стало все понятнее. Я писал адаптер, но не понимал часть написанного, по причине незнания что это, я смотрел официальную документацию, но фразы "этот метод устанавливает метку для объекта", что говорили про `setTag` и тому подобные — мне ничего не говорили. В вашем же коде все понятно (ну почти все. Я еще не до конца понимаю, как идет "круговорот методов и переменных" в адаптере), наглядно и... работает! По смыслу, осталось еще немного, так что программу допишу, а потом книгу по Android в руки и впе... читать!

Answer (score 2):

```
View rowView_1 = convertView;
View rowView_2 = convertView;
```

крашиться потому что у вас в `rowView_2=rowView_1`, и тип `ViewHolder_form_1`, а вы его пытаетесь привести к типу `ViewHolder_form_2`.

```
if (rowView_2 == null) {...}
else {
   (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();
}
```

тут у вас `rowView_2` не равно `null`, оно равно `rowView_1`, и соответственно тип тега там тоже 1.

Comment: А как это исправить? Нельзя сделать `new convertView`. Не допускать выполнение сразу обоих присваиваний — тоже не вышло.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо оперировать с холдерами после проверки позиции, а не до. Просто поместите второй блок кода в блок `else` (проверка позиции). Аналогичный блок операций с холдером1 - в `if(position < words_form_1.length)`

А ошибка говорит о том, что вы объект одного класса пытаетесь скастовать к другому. Почему так вышло - проследите свой код, порядок его выполнения и какое значение какой переменной присваивается в зависимости от позиции.

**UPD_0:**

Также попробуйте добавить методы для поддержки разных типов разметки для элементов.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position)
{
    return (position < words_form_1.length)?0:1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount ()
{
    return 2;
}
```

*Лично я сомневаюсь, что в этом дело, но вполне может помочь.*

**UPD_1:**

Я в коде вашем ошибок не вижу. Возможно они где-то в другом месте. Предлагаю такой костыль вам использовать - проверять какой класс в аргумент приходит.

```
if(rowView_2.getTag() instanceof ViewHolder_form_2)
{
     holder_2 = (ViewHolder_form_2) rowView_2.getTag();
}
else
{
    holder_2 = new ViewHolder_form_2();
}
```

Comment: Не работает - что это значит?

Comment: Дополнил. Я комментарии удалю, чтобы было чисто.

Comment: Юрий, а может есть какой-то другой способ загружать два массива в разметки? Мой вариант, видимо, не самый лучший...  Хотя другой будет тяжелее понять.

Comment: Теперь у вас уже другая ошибка. Вы пытаетесь где-то обратиться к сотому (индекс имею в виду) элементу массива, коий длинной в сто элементов. Т.е. к несуществуещему элементу. И вы опять забыли указать конкретную строчку, на коей ошибка вылезла.

Comment: У вас ошибка копи-паста. Вы вместо второго пытаетесь из первого массива значения извлечь. Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Исправил, но ошибка осталась. Та же.

Comment: Да и изначально программа не знает, какой массив я хотел загружать, а ошибка выхода за приделы должны была быть только через 2 строки.

Comment: У вас какой-то совсем странная подход... Что и зачем вы делаете непонятно. Я бы на вашем месте взял бы и с нуля написал простейший адаптер а потом уже пытался в него данные писать. Что у вас в данный момент происходит понять никак нельзя.

Comment: Я пробовал сначала самый простой, потом добавил `ViewHolder`, а когда начал пытаться разделить на два массива и две разметки (начало вопроса), начались ошибки...

Comment: Только что лежал, смотрел в потолок, думал и понял в чем косяк! Во втором массиве 100 элементов, а `position` равно 101. Присваивать нужно `position - words_form_1.lenght`. Завтра исправлю, уже спать охота :).