# Работа метода getView

Tags: java, android, listview, getview

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу понять принцип работы метода `getView` от `BaseAdapter`. История такова, что есть `ListView`, в который идут данные из Firebase. В зависимости от того, какие данные должны быть в нем, выбирается различный `Layout`. Вот как выглядит сейчас этот метод.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        if (mMessages.get(i).getUserId().equals(GlobalsMethods.currUserId))
            view = mInflater.inflate(mAltLayout, viewGroup, false);
        else
            view = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, viewGroup, false);
    }

    T model = mModels.get(i);
    populateView(view, model);
    return view;
}
```

Список `mMessages` обновляется в методах `addChildEventListener`. Если используется только один Layout, то никаких проблем нет. В противном случае это все работает некорректно. Некоторые элемента списка работают нормально, а некоторым присваивается неверный Layout. И при этом они еще могут меняться прямо во время работы. Если пробовать выводить данные в logcat, то там все, вроде, в порядке: нужным элементам присваиваются нужные значения. Например:

```
Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", String.valueOf(i));
Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", GlobalsMethods.currUserId);
Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", mMessages.get(i).getUserId() + " - " + mMessages.get(i).getMessage());
```

Выводит:

```
E/FirebaseListAdapter: 0
E/FirebaseListAdapter: test
E/FirebaseListAdapter: apk001 - rg
E/FirebaseListAdapter: mLayout
```

Данные верные, но, в итоге, у этого элемента списка оказывается `mAltLayout`.

Честно говоря, не понимаю, почему так происходит. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Адаптер для вывода айтемов разного типа должен выглядеть примерно так, как в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463634/177345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас несколько проблем:

1. Вы не используете механизм для различения когда какую разметку использовать, а именно метод `getItemViewType`
2. Вы не используете ViewHolder паттерн в адаптере.
3. Вы используете устаревший ListView.

Подробно как решается задача отображения различных типов разметок для современного RecyclerView написано тут: [Несколько разметок для айтемов в ListView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522489/17609)

Если е вы хотите всё же использовать устаревший `ListView` то аналогичный вопрос и ответ тут: [Как визуально выделить определенный айтем ListView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/17609)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, действительно помог второй вариант. Но можно все-таки задать вопрос? Почему этот вариант с типами работает, а мой вариант - нет? Ведь, по факту, мое условие if просто вынесено в отдельный метод. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Для экономии памяти система пытается отобразить уже загруженную разметку. Т.е. переменная view не всегда null и условие не выполнялось